# String manipulation in javascript object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to populate the following string if I have n data:

```
group.items[0].fname || group.items[1].fname ||..........|| group.items[n].fname
```

I have implemented following, I would like to know is there a better way to do that?

```
nam="";
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
  if(i==0)
    nam="groups.items["+i+"]"+".fname";
  else
    nam=nam+"||"+"group.items["+i+"]"+".fname";
 }
```

Comment: Why do you need such string? We can't help you  without knowing what exactly you are trying to achieve. If you are evaling that string you are doing something terribly wrong.

Comment: jsfiddle.net/opL8dq26 look at `series.name` format, is it clear?

Comment: So you are using kendo templates? Why not http://jsfiddle.net/6qnd510o/?

Comment: It is pretty good approach, however, if you take a look at legend, there are some extra commas coming to the picture. I need to investigate. The reason that I asked under `javascript` tag, because I have observed not many  from `kendo` developers in SOF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `data` is an array you can simply use `Array.prototype.map` to build array of substrings and then join them:

```js
var data = [1,2,3];

var nam = data.map(function(el, i) {
    return 'group.items[' + i + '].fname';
}).join('||');

alert(nam);
```

Comment: @mystackoverflow Just curious, now that you have the string, what do you plan to do with it? Print it out and put it up on the wall?

Comment: @torazaburo, i need it for the following http://jsfiddle.net/opL8dq26/ , look at `series.name` , is it clear enough?

Comment: @mystackoverflow That would have a great thing to put in your question.